# Opacity transition for a:hover not working

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, cross-browser, opacity

I want all elements that are links to show consistent behavior.

```
 a:hover { opacity: 0.5; }
```

This works in IE and Firefox, but the opacity (and associated CSS transition) is not properly applied to the child elements of the `<a>` tag in Chrome and Safari. If I add an explicit rule for a `<div>` as a child element, it works in Chrome and Safari:

```
 a:hover, a:hover div { opacity: 0.5; }
```

So far so good, and this has been asked and answered before. The problem that I have is that by adding the rule for the containing `<div>`, the opacity gets applied twice in IE and Firefox, making the element too transparent.

I need to cover both scenarios - `<a>` wrapping a `<div>` or not, without writing lots of explicit CSS rules. How can I do that?

http://liveweave.com/fMsz7m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What worked for me in Safari was adding `display: block` into the a tag

```
a:hover {                       
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition:  opacity 0.2s ease;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether this counts as a direct solution to your question (I'm not sure why the children aren't inheriting), but you can add `display: block` to the `a` in your css which will work (tested with Firefox and Chrome).

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzball007/r7z2D/)**

An alternative is to assign the hover to your `<div>`, parent of `<a>`.

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fuzzball007/r7z2D/2/)**

I feel as though there are better solutions/explanations out there, maybe this one will spark an idea for someone else.